# How to get altitude in Android

Tags: android

I use the Location class to get altitude, but it always returns 0.

Please tell me how to get altitude?

```
Location.getAltitude();
```

Comment: are you trying it in real device or emulator...

Comment: I try this on emulator, OS version 1.6

Comment: I think in emulator it won't show value for that you have to check in real device....

Answer (score 4):

Initially I used location.getAltitude() and it always retuned 0.0 . Then I came across https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-beginners/KNeLh905ip0 it helped me solve my problem. It works on actual real device.

```
private LocationProvider _locationProvider;
private LocationManager _locationManager;
   _locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
            .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    _locationProvider = _locationManager
            .getProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

     location = _locationManager.getLastKnownLocation 
                (LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER); 

     _locationProvider.supportsAltitude();                          
            hasaltitude = location.hasAltitude();
            double altitude = location.getAltitude();
            System.out.println("HasAltitude" + hasaltitude+"-"+altitude);
```

The value of "altitude" is will be in meters.

Comment: Hello friend, can you share complete demo source code with me... I also want to know How to calculate ALTITUDE

Comment: Does this return the altitude above ellipsoid or above mean sea level?

Answer (score 2):

Altitude is typically only available with GPS provider. You can check with available location provider if the support altitude:

```
locationProvider.hasAltitude();
```

Comment: I also tried this, when I use geo fix -121.45356 46.51119 4392 then it return true but altitude 0.0, but when I use geo nmea $GPRMC,081836,A,3751.65,S,14507.36,E,000.0,360.0,130998,011.3,E*62 then it return false.

Answer (score 0):

You need to obtain the user Location :
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html

The locationListener will give you a Location object, on which you can use the getAltitude() function.

Comment: yes i try it but it still return  0.0 value.I also try that in telnet console,geo fix -121.45356 46.51119 4392 and geo nmea $GPRMC,081836,A,3751.65,S,14507.36,E,000.0,360.0,130998,011.3,E*62

Answer (score 0):

With all the different methods to get location, while request a location for high accuracy it requires permission ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION